# How to properly form rm with xargs -a?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

A coworker showed me a nifty way of using rm and xargs for deleting filenames listed in a .txt - but I can't remember what he did.

I ran

```
echo | xargs -a file.txt
```

where file.txt contained

```
1
2
3
4
```

And it printed

```
1 2 3 4
```

My logic says that

```
rm | xargs -a file.txt
```

should delete the files I created titled 1 and 2 and 3 and 4.

But that is not the behavior I get.

How do I form this simple command?

Comment: The first works because if you don't supply a command to `xargs`, it default to `echo`. The `echo` before the pipe is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless file.txt is really large, xargs is unnecessary and this is equivalent:

```
rm $(<file.txt)
```

and portable (POSIX) too.

Comment: +1 I like your answer no need for the xargs. Note that if filenames contains spaces this solution will not work. On the other hand `xargs -I'{}' rm '{}'< file.txt` would.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you want:

```
xargs -a file.txt rm
```

The last argument to xargs should be the command you want it to run on all of the items in the file.

The solution proposed by Lynch is also valid and equivalent to this one.

Comment: +1 because you used the -a file.txt as requested by the OP. I did not include this form in my answer.

Comment: The `-a` option is not standard, I think it's a GNU extension.

Comment: @Lynch FYI, that link didn't work for me. If anyone else just sees the "man page for man," try this link instead: https://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/xargs

Answer (score 3):

Try this command:
`xargs rm < file.txt`

xargs take every line in input and append it to the command you specify.
so if file.txt contains:

```
a
b
```

then xargs will execute `rm a b`